# Bookmarking the page in which get attribute is written

Tags: php

I am starting PHP. While reading form from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) I came across this text,

### When to use method="post"?

> Information sent from a form with the POST method is invisible to
>   others and has no limits on the amount of information to send.
>
> However, because the variables are not displayed in the URL, it is not
>   possible to bookmark the page.

Now I understand what bookmarking is and the importance of security but I am unable to get why would anyone want to bookmark a user document submission page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one would *unless* the page is pporly coded, mixing UI with logic in some kind of weird god object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of a form submission shows the user some important information, such as an order confirmation number, then the user might be tempted to bookmark that page to save the order number.  If the page has been generated as the result of POST data, then this data will no longer be available when they use their bookmarks.